# UIActivityViewController not working as expected in Swift 2.0 while posting text to Facebook

Tags: swift2, ios9

Hi guys I have a question..

I am learning about UIActivityViewController to be used for custom swipe Actions like Share etc upon swiping a row within a UITableViewController

The UITableViewController contains a list of restaurants and I am trying to POST the restaurant Image and some default Text ( "Checking into the restaurant" ) on Facebook when Facebook is chosen from the Share menu after the Share button is clicked upon swiping a row in the UITableViewController

When I run the app on the simulator and chose the Facebook icon  in the Share options, the UIActivityViewController works fine i.e opens the iOS default posting page for Facebook with the default text message and the image of the chosen restaurant, however when I run the app on my iPhone and click on the Facebook icon, it opens the actual Facebook app posting page. On that page it shows the chosen restaurant image properly but does not show the default text message ???

I thought that iOS takes care of passing the text and image both to the Posting page. If image is shown properly then why not the text??

Can someone pls help me !!

You can download my project from the following link
https://github.com/vermau/FoodPin.git

Answer (score 0):

**Your question** : "If image is shown properly then why not the text??"

You can't share programatically generated text.
Refer this link, https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control

> Your app should not pre-fill any content to be shared. This is
>   inconsistent with Facebook Platform Policy, see Facebook Platform
>   Policy, 2.3.
>
> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message
>   parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the
>   person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

**Facebook removes pre filled text automatically.**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Hitendra. But I have doubt in mind that I want to clear. If this is the policy of Facebook then how come I was able to post default message along with the image on Facebook and Twitter from the same code by executing the program on the iPhone simulator instead of the actual iPhone. The simulator uses the OSX's default posting page for Facebook and Twitter. The entries were actually posted on my Facebook timeline that I confirmed by opening my Facebook account

Comment: Hi Hitendra, can you help me with a good resource to learn how to build a custom UIActivityViewController like different background colour etc